# Broken snap: dbeaver-ce

Tags: snap

dbeaver-ce is not launching from the dock, and this is the output in the terminal:

```
dbeaver-ce                                   
/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 50: /home/opyate/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
sed: can't read /home/opyate/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 238: /home/opyate/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
cp: cannot open '/home/opyate/.config/user-dirs.locale' for reading: Permission denied
/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 243: /home/opyate/.config/user-dirs.locale: Permission denied
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/gnome-platform/usr/share/mime': No such file or directory
Directory '/home/opyate/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/.local/share/mime/packages' does not exist!
/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 20: /snap/dbeaver-ce/93/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0: No such file or directory
ERROR: update-mime-database /home/opyate/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/.local/share/mime exited abnormally with status 1
ERROR: /snap/dbeaver-ce/93/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 exited abnormally with status 127

(process:18910): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:05:47.614: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Dbeaver: Cannot open display: 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=/home/opyate/snap/dbeaver-ce/93

(process:19017): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:05:47.778: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Dbeaver: Cannot open display: 
> Start DBeaver Standalone [org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.app.standalone 7.3.0.202011291229]
> Start Eclipse e4 Workbench [org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 1.11.200.v20200205-1503]
> Start Eclipse Workbench Model [org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench 2.1.700.v20200113-1422]
> Start Eclipse Jobs Mechanism [org.eclipse.core.jobs 3.10.700.v20200106-1020]
> Start Eclipse IDE UI [org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.17.0.v20200217-1511]
> Start DBeaver Core Plug-in [org.jkiss.dbeaver.core 7.3.0.202011291229]
> Start Core File Systems [org.eclipse.core.filesystem 1.7.700.v20200110-1734]
> Start Core Resource Management [org.eclipse.core.resources 3.13.700.v20200209-1624]
2020-12-11 11:05:48.802 - Initializing DBeaver 7.3.0
2020-12-11 11:05:48.802 - Host plugin: org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.app.standalone 7.3.0.202011291229
2020-12-11 11:05:48.802 - Initialize Core...
2020-12-11 11:05:48.803 - Can't find BC security provider. Use default JCE.
2020-12-11 11:05:48.803 - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
2020-12-11 11:05:48.900 - Initialize base platform...
> Start DBeaver UI Navigator [org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.navigator 1.0.46.202011291229]
2020-12-11 11:05:48.911 - Core initialized (109ms)
2020-12-11 11:05:48.912 - Create display
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:166)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.app.standalone.DBeaverApplication.getDisplay(DBeaverApplication.java:409)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.app.standalone.DBeaverApplication.updateSplashHandler(DBeaverApplication.java:335)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.app.standalone.DBeaverApplication.start(DBeaverApplication.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
Error updating splash shell
2020-12-11 11:05:48.915 - DBeaver 7.3.0.202011291229 is starting
2020-12-11 11:05:48.916 - OS: Linux 5.8.0-31-generic (amd64)
2020-12-11 11:05:48.916 - Java version: 1.8.0_275 by Private Build (64bit)
2020-12-11 11:05:48.916 - Install path: '/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/usr/share/dbeaver'
2020-12-11 11:05:48.916 - Instance path: 'file:/home/opyate/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/'
2020-12-11 11:05:48.916 - Memory available 94Mb/910Mb
```

Task manager shows a Java and dbeaver-ce process, but there's no GUI.

Please let me know why snaps just stop working? What is the most common thing folks do that breaks snaps?

Also, please don't tell me to re-install the snap, as I'll lose all my DB connections (I've created plenty). (I just re-installed the Postman snap, and lost all my collections, which had many requests in them.)

Or, if I really do have to reinstall them, please show me a way to keep my user data.

Comment: Broken snaps need to be reported to the developer of the snap, not here.  Just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

dbeaver works on my ubuntu 20.04

```
~$ snap info dbeaver-ce
installed:          7.3.0.202011291229            (93) 207MB -
```

I'd suggest you check the permission of directory /home/opyate/.config/user-dirs.dirs and directories above

mine has following access rights :

```
-rw-------  1 koen koen  633 dec  3 20:58 user-dirs.dirs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 koen koen 5 dec  3 20:58 user-dirs.locale
```

exporting/importing connections or keeping settings of dbeaver is discussed here : [https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=906#:~:text=There%20is%20project%20export%2Fimport,keep%20all%20UI%20settings%20too](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=906#:%7E:text=There%20is%20project%20export%2Fimport,keep%20all%20UI%20settings%20too).

in short :

There is project export/import feature (main menu File->Export/Import).
But the simplest way is to copy USER_HOME/.dbeaver folder to another machine. Thus you will keep all UI settings too. But before you do it please make sure you use the same DBeaver version on both machines.

for snaps the .dbeaver folder is stored here

```
~/snap/dbeaver-ce/93/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with dbeaver being opened a second time in a session.  You can resolve this problem without logging out by doing alt-f2, then typing "r" for the command and enter.  For whatever reason, the Gnome shell doesn't know when dbeaver terminates, and this restarts the shell with fresh state, so you can open it again.